# SizedBox does not work inside listview- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text("Select Time Slot"),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        width: 150,
        child: Card(
          child: Text(
            "11 AM - 1 PM",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

I expect that card occupies width 150, but it is taking complete width available.

[image]

What should I do to get the expected Result?

Comment: do you want to center the card with the 150 width

Comment: @sajithlakmal yes, exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to center the card with 150 width wrap it with center widget. center widget will set card width to 150 and will fill the remaining width by centering card to middle.

```
      Center(child: 
      SizedBox(
        width: 150,
        child: Card(
          child: Text(
            "11 AM - 1 PM",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ))
    ],
```

otherwise you can use Align widget to align the card as you preference.

Comment: read this article if you have extra time to understand flutter constraints better https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: even you don't need to specify width.

Comment: Thanks, that's a perfect solution to this question

Answer (score 1):

check this one:

```dart
home: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    centerTitle: true,
    title: const Text("Select Time Slot"),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: const <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: 150,
            child: Card(
              child: Text(
                "11 AM - 1 PM",
                style:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer or add comments to your code?

Comment: This works since the SizedBox is no longer a direct child of ListView and is now a child of the Row which allows it to have a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `ListView` try using `Column` and wrap it with `SingleChildScrollView`

```dart
 Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text("Select Time Slot"),
  ),
  body: Container(
height:300;
child:SingleChildScrollView(
   child:Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        width: 150,
        child: Card(
          child: Text(
            "11 AM - 1 PM",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
 ),
),
);
```